# Консольная оптимизация изображений

Tags: изображения, imagemagick, jpeg, bash, linux

Практическая задача: научиться "сохранять для веб" тяжеловесные фотографии (изображения) посредством консоли (bash, python, perl...). Уменьшать (resize)  изображения умею, а это нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну, это зависит от того, что вы вкладываете в понятие «сохранить для веб». Неужели уменьшения размера недостаточно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите тут http://ruhighload.com/post/Jpegoptim
И тут http://valerij.pp.ua/images-optimization-google-page-speed/

Answer (score 2):

```
convert source.jpg -quality 80 result.jpg
```

Comment: гениально и просто - понизить качество...(   
Больше никаких параметров, кроме качества и размеров не существует?

Comment: Как Вы это себе представляете чисто физически: пожать jpg или png картинку без потери качества?

Comment: я понимаю, что без потери качества не обойтись, но ищу бережный алгоритм сжатия  (применимый в консольно-серверной среде), цель именно оптимизация

Comment: jpg  это и так формат сжания, тоже самое, что zip, если грубо. Задайте вопрос нормально, а то пока что мой ответ самый правильный. ^_^

Comment: @Bimawa ваш ответ на вопрос "как копировать в консоли",  мне нужна оптимизация  - и сжатие jpg - возможно, только при нахождении приемлимых параметров, оно приобретет задуманный практический интерес

Comment: Ну вообще слово "сохранять" синоним "копировать". Во-вторых, поправьте вопрос. В-третьих, мифические "приемлимые параметры" зависят прямопропорционально от применения картинки. Если это Обнаженная девушка 5К разрешения, то вряд ли ее стоит вообще как-то сжимать. Если же это ваша Аватарка 50x50 поинтов в углу экрана, то тогда да, учите [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)

Answer (score 1):

```
cp resized_image.jpg /var/www/mysuite.ru/webFolder/
```

***UPD***

Ну вообще слово "сохранять" синоним "копировать". Во-вторых, поправьте вопрос. В-третьих мифические "приемлимые параметры" зависят прямопропорционально от применения картинки. Если это Обнаженная девушка 5К разрешения то врядли ее стоит вообще как-то сжимать. Если же это ваша Аватарка 50x50 поинтов в углу экрана, то тогда да учите [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)

Comment: зачем мне копировать?

Comment: ну Выж писали `Уменьшать (resize) изображения умею` "сохранять для веб" не умею ) Ну вот копируйте в нужную папочку отресайзнутые изображения. И PROFIT

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ:

`for file in *; do convert $file  -resize 1000 -quality 80 $file; done`

[@Дож](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6) - спасибо тебе, твой ответ был всех ближе к истине.